# iOS draw graph with gradient on mapkit

Tags: ios, core-graphics, mkmapview, gradient, routes

I try to modify the Breadcrumb example from Apple in the way that the drawn path has a gradient. I can not make I work. The colour of the path is black and not gradient. 
Someone got an idea?

```
if (path != nil)
{

    CGContextAddPath(context, path);
    CGContextSetLineJoin(context, kCGLineJoinRound);
    CGContextSetLineCap(context, kCGLineCapRound);
    CGContextSetLineWidth(context, lineWidth);

    CGContextReplacePathWithStrokedPath(context);
    path = CGContextCopyPath(context);

    CGContextAddPath(context, path);

    CGContextSaveGState(context); {
        CGColorSpaceRef rgb = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
        CGGradientRef gradient = CGGradientCreateWithColors(rgb, (__bridge CFArrayRef)@[
                                                            (__bridge id)[UIColor greenColor].CGColor,
                                                            (__bridge id)[UIColor redColor].CGColor
                                                            ], (CGFloat[]){ 0.0f, 1.0f });
        CGColorSpaceRelease(rgb);

     CGPoint startPoint = CGPointMake(MKMapRectGetMidX(clipRect), MKMapRectGetMinY(clipRect));
     CGPoint endPoint = CGPointMake(MKMapRectGetMidX(clipRect), MKMapRectGetMaxY(clipRect));

        CGContextClip(context);
        CGContextDrawLinearGradient(context, gradient, startPoint, endPoint, 0);
        CGGradientRelease(gradient);
    } CGContextRestoreGState(context);

    CGContextAddPath(context, path);
    CGPathRelease(path);

    CGContextDrawPath(context, kCGPathFillStroke);

}
```

Comment: You might try calling `CGContextDrawPath` **before** `CGPathRelease`. I think that could cause a problem.

Comment: I found the soultion myself. The problem are startpoint and endpoint. When you use

    CGRect bbox = CGContextGetPathBoundingBox(context);
CGPoint startPoint = bbox.origin;
CGPoint endPoint = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMaxX(bbox),CGRectGetMaxY(bbox));

the colour of the path is gradient.